# transforming a cdf with a function of $x$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a cdf $F(x)$ defined over 0,1.  I have a function, $q(x)$, which returns a number between $x$ and $1$.  I would like to define a new cdf, $G(x)$, such that $G(q(x)) = F(x)$.  I would think there is a simple way to do this, but I can't figure it out.  Can anyone help me with the process?

Thank you!

Comment: The function $q(x)$ must be monotonically increasing. Then $G(x) = F(q^{-1}(x))$, where $y=q^{-1}(x)$ is the unique solution to equation $x=q(y)$.

Comment: If F is only nondecreasing, q may be only nondecreasing as well, provided it is constant on intervals related to those where F is constant.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case, both F and q are monotonically increasing. This helps!  I would "accept" if in answer form :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is a copy of points made in comments by @Sasha and me.)

If $F$ is increasing, $q$ must be increasing. Then  $G(x)=F(q^{-1}(x))$, where $y=q^{-1}(x)$ is the unique solution of the equation $x=q(y)$. If $F$ is only nondecreasing, $q$ may be only nondecreasing as well, provided $q$ is constant on intervals related to those where $F$ is constant.